# How to prevent query injection on Google Big Query

Tags: java, sql, google-bigquery

I'm writing some Google `Big-query` dynamic reporting utilities to our website, that will allow users to select a parameter to be replaced in the query. Given this query "template":

```
SELECT  name ,
        birthday
FROM    [dataset.users]
WHERE   registration_date = '{{registration_date}}'
```

we take the {{registration_date}} value from the user and replace it in the template, resulting in a query:

```
SELECT  name ,
        birthday
FROM    [dataset.users]
WHERE   registration_date = '2013-11-11'
```

How I can prevent `sql-injection` like attacks in this scenario, given that I'm executing the queries using the Google `Big-query` client API, 
and the API don't allow one to use positioned parameters as on traditional `RDBMS` apis.

Comment: validate the user input for you use it in your query.

Comment: @Dan - Easier said than done.  Preventing SQL injection is like cryptography - best left to the professionals.  And even they often get it wrong (see `addslashes` followed by `mysql_escape_string` followed by `mysql_real_escape_string`)

Comment: Thanks @DanBracuk, however, doing my own poor man validation is potentially dangerous. Do you have any kind of pointers on good validation API/tool/tips in Java?

Comment: There are two things you have to do.  One is to make sure you have the expected data types.  Dates should be dates, numbers should be numbers, etc.  The next thing you have to do is to escape special charaters such as apostrophes.  When you get right down to it, the datatype thing should be happening even if you do use query parameters.  If you are using java for your application code, I suggest adding a java tag to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the launch of standard SQL in BigQuery, it has been possible to use [query parameters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) as a way of preventing SQL injection. In your query, you can specify named parameters using `@` followed by a name, e.g.

```
SELECT x, y FROM T WHERE x <= @x_max AND y = @target_y;
```

You can then provide the parameter values through the `query_parameters` attribute of the API.

Answer (score 7):

Check "Defense Option 3: Escaping All User Supplied Input" in OWASP:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_3:_Escaping_All_User_Supplied_Input

UPDATE: Parametrized queries are an option now

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries

Comment: Thanks Fh for your answer. The link you provided has codedcs for MySQL and Oracle. For BigQuery, would encoding the input with the MySQL ANSI mode suffice?

Comment: Is this still the preferred solution 2 years later?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: What to do if I'm building query from array of field names, so I want to fill in part in SELECT {fields} from {table_name}? Just check field names using some strict regexp/whitelist?