# How to set an SQL parameters in Apps Scripts and BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am trying to avoid a sql injection. This topic has been dealt with in Java ([How to prevent query injection on Google Big Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805617/how-to-prevent-query-injection-on-google-big-query)) and Php.

How is this accomplished in App Scripts? I did not find how to add a parameter to a SQL statement. Here is what I had hoped to do:

```
  var sql = 'SELECT [row],etext,ftext FROM [hcd.hdctext] WHERE (REGEXP_MATCH(etext, esearch = ?) AND REGEXP_MATCH(ftext, fsearch = ?));';


  var queryResults;
  var resource = {
      query: sql,
      timeoutMs: 1000,
      esearch='r"[^a-zA-z]comfortable"',
      fsearch='r"[a-z,A-z]confortable"'
  };

  queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(resource,projectNumber);
```

And then have esearch and fsearch filled in with the values (which could be set elsewhere).

That does not work, according to the doc.

Any suggestions on how to get a parameter in an SQL query? (I could not find a setString function...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, BigQuery doesn't support this type of parameter substitution. It is on our list of features to consider, and I'll bump the priority since it seems like this is a common request.

The only suggestion that I can make in the mean time is that if you are building query strings by hand, you will need to make sure you escape them carefully (which is a non-trivial operation).

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lJewIWVI5s insisted that apps scripts had that feature across the board (at 15:43 ff), but it looks like that function didn't quite make it out the door. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Has this been implemented yet?

Comment: alas, no, this has not yet been implemented.

Comment: Any update of this? This should definitely be a thing by 2016.

Comment: Search for queryParameters on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query